# Open .chm file at specific page/topic using command line arguments

Tags: c++, chm, view-helpers

I am attempting to open a .chm file(A windows help file) at a specific page/topic by using a system call in C++.

I can successfully open the .chm file to the start page through the following code, but **how can I open a .chm file to a specific page/topic inside the help file?**

```
system("start c:/help/myhelp.chm");
```

PS: I know system is evil/discouraged but the system part is not really relevant its the command line arguments I pass with the .chm file(that will specify what page I want to open) that I am trying to determine.

Comment: Take a look at this link: http://www.help-info.de/en/Help_Info_HTMLHelp/hh_command.htm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok the arguments are like so:

```
system(" /Q /E:ON /C HH.EXE ms-its:myChm.chm::myPageName.htm");
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this langauge-independent solution.  In Python, `subprocess.Popen("hh,exe ms-its:C:/path/x.chm::/dir/pg.html")` works great and I will probably use it on Windows to display Idle help.  I am curious whether you know what the `/Q /E:ON /C` flags are supposed to do.

Answer (score 6):

There is an API in the Windows SDK called HtmlHelp in the HtmlHelp.h file. You can call like so:

```
HtmlHelp(GetDesktopWindow(), L"C:\\helpfile\\::/helptopic.html", HH_DISPLAY_TOPIC, NULL);
```

The [Microsoft Docs - HtmlHelpA function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/htmlhelp/nf-htmlhelp-htmlhelpa) provides more information about the function. `HtmlHelp()` will normally resolve to `HtmlHelpA()` or `HtmlHelpW()` depending on whether Unicode compiler option is set or not.

See as well [Microsoft Docs - HTML Help API Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/htmlhelp/html-help-api-overview).

Answer (score 2):

Another option - use ShellExecute.  The Microsoft help is not easy to use.  This approach is much easier and in line with your question.  Here is a quick routine to open a help file and pass an ID number.  I have just set up some simple char’s so you can see what is going on:

```
    void DisplayHelpTopic(int Topic)
{

    // The .chm file usually has the same name as the application - if you don’t want to hardcode it...
    char *CmndLine = GetCommandLine(); // Gets the command the program started with.
    char Dir[255];
    GetCurrentDirectory (255, Dir);
    char str1[75] = "\0"; // Work string
    strncat(str1, CmndLine, (strstr(CmndLine, ".exe") - CmndLine)); // Pull out the first parameter in the command line (should be the executable name) w/out the .exe
    char AppName[50] = "\0";
    strcpy(AppName, strrchr(str1, '\\')); // Get just the name of the executable, keeping the '\' in front for later when it is appended to the directory

    char parms[300];
    // Build the parameter string which includes the topic number and the fully qualified .chm application name
    sprintf(parms,_T("-mapid %d ms-its:%s%s.chm"), Topic, Dir, AppName);
    // Shell out, using My Window handle, specifying the Microsoft help utility, hh.exe, as the 'noun' and passing the parameter string we build above
// NOTE: The full command string will look like this:
//   hh.exe -mapid 0 ms-its:C:\\Programs\\Application\\HelpFile.chm
    HINSTANCE retval = ShellExecute(MyHndl, _T("open"), _T("hh.exe"), parms, NULL, SW_SHOW);
}
```

The topics are numbered within your .chm file.  I set up a #define for each topic so if I had to change the .chm file I could just change the include file to match and not have to worry about searching through the code for hardcoded values.